# AngularJS validate included form(Ionic framework)

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm trying to validate a form that was included using ng-include.

HTML:

```js
function submit() {
  if($scope.form.$invalid) {
    return;
    }
  }

$scope.submit = submit;
```

```html
<form name='form' ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
  <div ng-include="'my_form_inputs.html'"></div>
</form>
```

when i try to submit i get an error that form.$invalid is null.
i know ng-include creates another scope within the controller's scope, but is there no way to validate this form?

it seems like i would have to duplicate the entire form elements if i want to create an edit page for this form.

any idea?

Comment: you need to again place form tag inside your view..

Comment: I created this plunker that seems to work, can you create one the demonstrates it not working? http://plnkr.co/edit/CPhENXYXP7csvW00up2I?p=preview

Comment: your plunker work! but when i try to do it in my project i get an error.. i wonder if it is because i'm using Ionic framework

Comment: you can always use a hack like <form name="form" ng-init="$parent.form=form">